# Libruby-extras

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails

Не могу поставить пакеты. Ubuntu 12.04. Получаю это:

> E: Unable to locate package libruby-extras
> E: Unable to locate package libruby1.8-extras
> E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'libruby1.8-extras'

Answer (score 1):

Используй путь [менеджера версий руби](https://rvm.io/), юный падаван.

```
rvm requirements
```

Comment: sudo apt-get install mysql-client libmysqlclient-dev